# Using gradient to find an equation of a plane tangent to the graph

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was trying to solve a problem I saw on my calculus book. I have the solution manual but I fail to understand the solution. Here is the problem:

find an equation of the plane tangent to the graph of the given function at the point whose x and y coordiantes are given

$f (x,y)=\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)}$ at  $P(1,2)$

my attempt at solution
$\nabla f(1,2)=\frac {3}{25}i-\frac{4}{25}j$

$\frac{3}{25}(x-1)-\frac{4}{25}(y-2)=z$

But as it the solution to the problem is 
$\frac{3}{25}(x-1)-\frac{4}{25}(y-2)=z-\frac{1}{5}$

and I don't understand where that 1/5 coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Recall that for a $\mathcal{C}^1$-function $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, the graph of it's linearization defines the tangent plane for $\textbf{p} \in U$. The linearization is given by,

$$ z = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}(\textbf{p})(x-p_0) +\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}(\textbf{p})(y-p_1) + \color{red}{f({p})}$$

where $\textbf{p} = (p_0,p_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

What is $z = f(P)$? Now, consider your solution at $P$: $\frac{3}{25}(1-1)-\frac{4}{25}(2-2) = z \implies z = 0$.

This is not an answer, but I cannot comment with my low rep.

Perhaps, to answer your question, the $-\frac{1}{5}$ comes about as a result of shifting your plane along the $z$-axis. Your tangent plane was just parallel, but not coincident with the solution.